# Create a generic "getColumn" method for a database class (Java)

Tags: java, database, generics, parameters

I have a Database class that encapsulates the functionality of `java.sql.*` classes.  Basically you subclass it in order to create a connection to a particular database, and then you can use its methods to perform common operations.

One operation I'd like to implement is a `getColumn()` method.  If the expected database column is a String datatype, I could do the following:

```
public List<String> getColumn(String sql) throws SQLException
{
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = _stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rs.next())
    {
        results.add(rs.getString(1));
    }
    return results;
}
```

But I would like to genericize this method with a template parameter, and use the proper `ResultSet.get*` method to populate the `ArrayList`.

Something like this:

```
public <T> List<T> getColumn(String sql) throws SQLException
{
    List<T> results = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = _stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rs.next())
    {
        // if T is String, do:
        // results.add(rs.getString(1));
        // if T is Integer, do:
        // results.add(rs.getInt(1));
        // etc.
    }
    return results;
```

I'm sure there must be an elegant way to do this.  Thoughts?  Am I going about this the wrong way?
    }

Comment: Is this for learning purposes or for real-world use?

Comment: Real world case.

Comment: Then don't reinvent the wheel. It's time-consuming and you'll miss cases. Use `JdbcTemplate` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake is attempting a method with signature like:

```
<T> T fn()
```

In Java there is no way to find out within an invocation of `fn` what `T`. The choices are return `null`, unsafely cast an object that may or may not be a `T` or throw an exception. If you have something similar but a return type of `List<T>` the only thing you could store in that list is `null`.

So what to do. Typically you would pass in an argument to create the required type. A function object, for instance. (I would use `java.util.function.Function`, but checked exceptions get in the way.)

```
List<String> names = getColumn(
    "SELECT [...]",
    (result, column) -> result.getString(column)
);
[...]

interface ResultFunction<T> {
    T get(ResultSet results, int column) throws SQLException;
}

public <T> List<T> getColumn(
    String sql, ResultFunction<T> function
) throws SQLException {
    List<T> values = new ArrayList<>();
    try (ResultSet result = _stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
        while (result.next()) {
            values.add(function.get(result, 1));
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

You may want to expand the functionality of `ResultFunction` and perhaps use enums.